# Reading a string by each character in stdinput in c to do a conversion

Tags: c

so I need to create a program in C that reads a string character by character and output each character in the string's corresponding ascii decimal/hexadecimal/octal representation. This program should stop reading the string upon reaching a newline character.

For example given "Hi" the program should print "72 105" if I chose the decimal option.

So my idea is to read the string provided character by character into a large character array checking each character to see if it is the new line and then afterwards looping through elements 0-N where N is the index where char_array[N]=='\n' printing each element as its decimal representation.

So far, I've come up with this code which should cover the decimal representation case but I've come across an error I'm unsure how to troubleshoot.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char char_arr[1000],conversion,temp;
    int i=-1,j=0;
    printf("Integer conversion in decimal (d), octal (o), or hexadecimal (h)? ");
    scanf("%c",&conversion);
    
    printf("Enter a message: ");
    do{ i++;
        if(scanf("%c",&char_arr[i])!=1){
        break;}

    }
    while(char_arr[i]!='\n');
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("%d",char_arr[j]);
    }
    
    
    return 0;
    }
```

When I run this program it simply prints
Integer conversion in decimal (d), octal (o), or hexadecimal (h)? d
Enter a message:

and gives me no option to enter a message.

Does anyone have any thoughts or explanations for why this would occur? I'm new to C.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&conversion);` You effectively type in `"d\n"`. Which means the newline character is not yet read after that `scanf`. So you should be able to see what happens next.

Comment: Yes @kaylum that makes sense. How should I deal with that?

Comment: Use `fgets` for the first input line. Also, it would be simpler just to use `fgets` to get the next line as well - if  your task requirement doesn't prohibit that. If you can't use `fgets` at all then write a function that mimics `fgets` - continues to read characters until a newline is found or the buffer is full.

Comment: oh my god @kaylum I appreciate it. I just read about that function and it suits this perfectly thank you!

Comment: Yes, a few people in the past have had the need to do the same thing :-)